# A locally Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider for $\delta>0$ the function $$\vec F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3:\vec F(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}-x-\delta(y^2+z^2)+1\\-y+\delta xy\\ -z+\delta xz\end{pmatrix}.$$

Is this map locally Lipschitz? (Recall that $\vec F$ is locally Lipschitz if for all $a\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and all $r>0$ there is a $K\in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $$|\vec F(x)-\vec F(a)|\le K\cdot|x-a| $$ for all $x$ in the open balls centered at $a$).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every $C^1$ map is locally Lipschitz ([mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your vector field $F \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$. This is a sufficient condition for it to be *locally* lipschitz: indeed, by Weierstrass' theorem $F^{\prime}$ (I mean the jacobian, of course) is bounded on every compact subset of $\mathbb R^{3}$ and therefore the function is locally Lipschitz (to prove this you may also use the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables) for function of more variables).